# How to make Reliance Netconnect+ modem work on linux?

Tags: linux, modem

I am not able to connect internet through Reliance Netconnect+ on my Fedora 14? It is working properly on Windows.

Whenever I run wvdial command, I see below error:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

I see below logs while connecting to device:

```
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.144145] usb 4-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.294153] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1505
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.294163] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.294171] usb 4-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.294176] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.294182] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-2"
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 2 was not an MTP device
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.670958] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.671294] scsi5 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.671415] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    Jun 12 09:53:35 localhost kernel: [ 2180.671417] USB Mass Storage support registered.
    Jun 12 09:53:36 localhost kernel: [ 2181.677229] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
    Jun 12 09:53:37 localhost kernel: [ 2181.707188] sr1: scsi-1 drive
    Jun 12 09:53:37 localhost kernel: [ 2181.709536] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
```

On running command

```
usb_modeswitch -H -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1505


    Looking for default devices ...
     Found devices in default mode or class (1)
    Accessing device 002 on bus 004 ...
    Using endpoints 0x08 (out) and 0x87 (in)
    Using endpoints 0x08 (out) and 0x87 (in)
    Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
    Looking for active driver ...
     OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
     OK, driver "usb-storage" detached

    SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
    -------------------------
      Vendor String: HUAWEI
       Model String: Mass Storage
    Revision String: 2.31
    -------------------------

    USB description data (for identification)
    -------------------------
    Manufacturer: HUA�WEI TECHNOLOGIES
         Product: HUAWEI Mobile
      Serial No.: �������������������
    -------------------------
    Sending Huawei control message ...
     OK, Huawei control message sent
    -> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

I ran below command also but no luck.

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1505
```

Ran wvdial after above command:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
```

What can I do to make Reliance Netconnect+ run on my linux machine - Fedora 14?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using Sakis3g script.

Go to google and search for 'sakis3g source forge' download the script and copy to /usr/bin
untar the file

```
    sudo chmod +x sakis3g
    sudo sakis3g
```

Once the window opens up choose connect 3g -> interface #3 - > apn username & password

Hit ok and it should connect